# webgl with no libraries how do i create a floor infinite grid

Tags: glsl, webgl

Using only webgl with no libraries how do I create an infinite grid on the floor of my scene?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this question: [Drawing an infinite ground plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75953324/drawing-an-infinite-ground-plane)

[image]